# Spring boot with javaFx

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx

I'm working on a java desktop app using spring boot and javaFx.
it's a crud app so I'm working with mysql database
I want the controllers to be both spring boot and javaFx controllers, and for that I used `setControllerFactory()`.
here is my application

Application:

```
package com.gi.quizui;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javafx.application.Application.launch(QuizApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

QuizApplication:

```
package com.gi.quizui;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public class QuizApplication extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(com.gi.quizui.Application.class).run();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        applicationContext.publishEvent(new StageReadyEvent(stage));
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        applicationContext.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }

    class StageReadyEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
        public StageReadyEvent(Stage stage) {
            super(stage);
        }

        public ConfigurableApplicationContext getAppContext() {

            return applicationContext;
        }

        public Stage getStage() {

            return ((Stage) getSource());
        }
    }
}
```

and stage initializer:

```
package com.gi.quizui;
import com.gi.quizui.QuizApplication.StageReadyEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class StageInitializer implements ApplicationListener<StageReadyEvent> {

    @Value("classpath:fxml/quiz.fxml")
    private Resource quizResource;

    public StageInitializer(@Value("${spring.application.ui.title}") String applicationTitle) {
        this.applicationTitle = applicationTitle;
    }

    private String applicationTitle;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(StageReadyEvent event) {
        Stage stage = event.getStage();
        ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext = event.getAppContext();
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(quizResource.getURL());
            fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
            Parent parent = fxmlLoader.load();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(parent, 800, 600));
            stage.setTitle(applicationTitle);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error : (edit)

```
Exception in Application start method
2021-01-16 15:37:15.286  INFO 8652 --- [lication Thread] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-01-16 15:37:15.320  INFO 8652 --- [lication Thread] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-01-16 15:37:15.343  INFO 8652 --- [lication Thread] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/FacilOrdi/IdeaProjects/quizManagement/target/classes/fxml/quiz.fxml:7

    at com.gi.quizui.StageInitializer.onApplicationEvent(StageInitializer.java:40)
    at com.gi.quizui.StageInitializer.onApplicationEvent(StageInitializer.java:16)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:426)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
    at com.gi.quizui.QuizApplication.start(QuizApplication.java:20)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/FacilOrdi/IdeaProjects/quizManagement/target/classes/fxml/quiz.fxml:7

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at com.gi.quizui.StageInitializer.onApplicationEvent(StageInitializer.java:35)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.gi.controllers.QuizController' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1177)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:938)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    ... 19 more
```

controller:

```
package com.gi.controllers;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class QuizController {


}
```

I don't understand why it is not working, I've found related questions but I don't get how it works. It would be very helpful if there are other alternatives to do this.

Comment: What is line  of `QuizApplication`?

Comment: @dan1st I don't understand

Comment: Was a numpad problem. I meant _What is line 20 of `QuizApplication`?_.

Comment: `applicationContext.publishEvent(new StageReadyEvent(stage));`

Comment: line 40 : `throw new RuntimeException();`

Comment: Can you print the IOException that you catch in StageInitializer? You can do this by changing `throw new RuntimeException();` to `throw new RuntimeException(e);`

Comment: Did you try to autowire a class named `QuizController`? Spring Boot does not find this class. It needs to be made available as spring been (either by annotating it with `@Component` or using a method that is annotated with `@Bean` and returns an instance of it).

Comment: QuizController is annotated `@Component`

Comment: Post your `QuizController` class, and include package statements in all your posted code. The controller class needs to be appropriately annotated and needs to be in a package which the application context will scan.

Comment: Try adding the annotation `@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.gi.quizui","com.gi.controllers"})` to your `Application` class.

Comment: @James_D thank you that solved my problem

Comment: I added that as an answer, with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be aware of classes which have annotations such as `@Component`, etc., Spring Boot needs to scan through part of the classpath at startup time.  By default it will scan the package containing the class you pass to `SpringApplicationBuilder` (`Application` in your case) and all subpackages.

So with the way you have things set up, it will scan `com.gi.quizui` and all subpackages.

Your `QuizController` class is not in a sub-package of `com.gi.quizui`; it is in `com.gi.controllers`. Consequently it won't be found.

The recommendation in the Spring Boot documentation is actually to have the `Application` class in the highest-level package that contains classes or resources, which is likely `com.gi` in your case. If you move that class to that package, it should fix the issue.

Alternatively, you can override the default behavior using the `@ComponentScan` annotation:

```
package com.gi.quizui;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan ;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.gi.quizui","com.gi.controllers"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javafx.application.Application.launch(QuizApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

A typesafe alternative is to use the `basePackageClasses` parameter instead of `basePackages`:

```
package com.gi.quizui;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan ;

import com.gi.controllers.QuizController ;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={Application.class, QuizController.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javafx.application.Application.launch(QuizApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```